# Is there a real word to replace "examplary"? (note: not exemplary)

Tags: single-word-requests

"Examplary" doesn't appear to be a real English word, and I'm not searching for *exemplary* because I'm just interested in practical, instructive examples, not necessarily anything especially good nor a particularly desirable model.

What I'm looking for would be used in some form of the following awkward but *examplary* sentence:

> The speaker mentioned several occurrences in an *examplary* way, showing how each was a helpful example of the class of events. They found that immediately after a definition and explanation this *example-providing* process was important in order for the students to grasp the underlying concept.

Is there a real English word that would work the way I'm trying to use the fake word *examplary?*

Comment: I'd rephrase: The speaker gave examples of several occurrences, showing.... Indeed, your later phrase "helpful example" might mean you don't have to have an earlier word with a similar meaning at all: The speaker mentioned several occurrences, showing how each was a helpful example of the class of events.

Comment: @RosieF yes indeed; I've warned that the sentence was "awkward but *examplary*" Sadly it's not *exemplary* as well. :-)

Comment: The word anecdotal should do it for you.

Comment: *"Examplary" doesn't appear to be a real English word,"* OED: **exemplary  = A. adj.1a. That sets or affords a good example; admirable, commendable; (later also more generally) excellent, outstanding, perfect.** 2010   Los Angeles Times 30 Dec. d1   *He's embraced by hero-worshipers as an exemplary Christian.* Your problem is that your context does not really support the word,.

Comment: @Greybeard I'm sorry I don't catch your meaning. There are two words, one with an "e" and one with an "a" and I don't know which word "the word" refers to. Also, by "your context" do you mean the context in the example in the block quote?

Comment: "Examplary" and  "exemplary" are the same word. The spelling "examplary" was last used around the 15th century: **OED: Forms:  15–16 examplarie, 15–16 exemplarie, 15– examplary *(now nonstandard)*, 15– exemplary, 16 exempleary.** *do you mean the context in the example in the block quote?* Yes.

Comment: @Greybeard I think I understand your meaning now, "examplary" is *not* not a real English word. My construct (for which "instantial" seems to work) has the same spelling as a real word, albeit a spelling not currently in use. *Thanks!*

Comment: The unmarked term is, as LPH says, 'instantial'. 'Used for the purposes of example.' Terms such as 'archetypal', 'paradigmatic' refer to 'the killer example', the one that defines the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjective "**instantial**" seems to have the exact  meaning sought.

> (SOED) Of or pertaining to an instance or instances; providing an instance

"Instance" can be considered a good synonym of "example".

*Addition providing a comparison of frequency of use with the possibility of using "by way of example" instead (term proposed in [user Greybeard's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/548089/349876)'s answer)*

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I want to say it doesn't, but it does indeed seem to work quite well. I can't figure out any way that an example of something isn't also an instance of it or vice versa. Thanks!

Comment: I see "instantial" as a $10 word: one that is going to cause the reader to stumble (and maybe reach for a dictionary.) I would say *"The speaker mentioned several occurrences **by way of example**,"*

Comment: @Greybeard I guess it's time to say "Live and learn!".

Comment: @Greybeard I reckon, that is a good choice; make an answer of it, it seems worth an answer.

Comment: @uhoh You will note that "example" is used as part of an prepositional adverbial phrase and is uncountable. It may applies to the verb, not the object.

Comment: @Greybeard I'm getting the idea, albeit slowly.

Comment: @uhoh Having thought about it, I feel that "by way of example" is probably a free modifier, (https://www.thoughtco.com/free-modifier-grammar-1690807), hence its adverbial quality.

Answer (score 0):

> "Examplary" doesn't appear to be a real English word,"

"**Examplary**" and "**exemplary**" are the same word. The spelling "ex**a**mplary" was last used around the 15th century:

OED:

> **Forms: 15–16 examplarie, 15–16 exemplarie, 15– examplary *(now nonstandard)*, 15– exemplary, 16 exempleary.**
>
> **exemplary** = **A. adj.1a. That sets or affords a good example; admirable, commendable; *(later also more generally) excellent, outstanding, perfect.***
>
> 2010 Los Angeles Times 30 Dec. d1 *He's embraced by hero-worshipers as an exemplary Christian.*

Your problem is that your quoted context does not really support the word in its current/main meaning.

I would say *"The speaker mentioned several occurrences **by way of example**,"*

Comment: "Your problem is..." makes me uncomfortable because I do not have a problem. I have made a single-word-request and explained that *exemplary* will not work because it's definition is different. However thank you for filling me in on a 15th century spelling of a different word that coincides with my example.

Comment: @uhoh I think that, ubnfortunately, you have misunderstood. "Your problem" refers to your problem in choosing the correct word. You asked the question about that subject - it is therefore to be assumed that you had a problem.

Comment: I see. I would write "The challenge here is that the quoted context..." so as not to single out another SE user personally. I try (but fail regularly) to address the question itself rather than the OP. I try to write timeless answers that feel as useful to any reader in the future as to the OP of the moment.